# Using .SVG files to append icons to Nodes in d3JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am working with a nodes and edges graph in react with d3JS and I need to import SVG icons to replace each node. Currently the nodes are all just circles however they need to be icons as styled in the monos.svg file. Each node has a "type" attribute in data and this must match the "sybol id" in monos.svg
The graph data looks like this:

```
var data = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "type": "all"

                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "glc"

                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "type": "alt"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "type": "glc"
                }

            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": "0",
                    "target": "1",
                    "length": 0.1
                },

                {
                    "source": "1",
                    "target": "2",
                    "length": 0.1
                },
                {
                    "source": "1",
                    "target": "3",
                    "length": 0.1
                },


            ]
        };
```

the nodes decleration looks like so:

```
var node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "blue");
```

and the monos.svg which holds the styling for each symbol id looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   style="display: none;">
<defs>
<symbol id="all"  viewBox="0 0 50 50" data-abbr="All"  data-shortname="D-Allose">
            <path style="fill:#A54399;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.4164;" d="M1.7,25c0,12.8,10.4,23.3,23.3,23.3S48.3,37.8,48.3,25
        S37.8,1.7,25,1.7S1.7,12.2,1.7,25z"/>
        </symbol>
<symbol id="alt"  viewBox="0 0 50 50" data-abbr="Alt" data-shortname="L-Altrose">
            <path style="fill:#F69EA1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.4164;" d="M1.7,25c0,12.8,10.4,23.3,23.3,23.3S48.3,37.8,48.3,25
            S37.8,1.7,25,1.7S1.7,12.2,1.7,25z"/>
        </symbol>
<symbol id="glc"  viewBox="0 0 50 50" data-abbr="Glc" data-shortname="D-Glucose">
            <path style="fill:#0072BC;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.4164;" d="M1.7,25c0,12.8,10.4,23.3,23.3,23.3S48.3,37.8,48.3,25
            S37.8,1.7,25,1.7S1.7,12.2,1.7,25z"/>
        </symbol>     
</defs>
</svg>
```

the UI looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1R1U.png)

Please let me know if there is a way to append the "sybol id" style matching to the "type" onto each node.

I have tried having a fetch mono function that looks like this:

```
function fetchMono(svgFile, mID) {
    let symbolElement
    fetch(svgFile)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(svgText => {
            const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
            tempDiv.innerHTML = svgText;

            // Find and store the symbol element by its ID
            symbolElement = tempDiv.querySelector('#'+ mID);

            // Append the symbol to the container
            return (document.getElementById('symbol-container').appendChild(symbolElement));
        })

        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading SVG:',);
            return null
        });


}
```

that returns the icon given:

```
var s = fetchMono("monos.svg", nodes.type)
```

this didn't work and even if it did I don't know how to append the variable s to each node.

Comment: You can append a `<use>` element pointing to the symbol ID like so `<use href="monos.svg#alt" />` (Provided your svg is on same domain - you don't need a fetch). A symbol element is invisible by default that's probably why you don't see anything appended.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. .append(<use href="monos.svg#glc"/>) gives a pasring error so i tried .append("svg", <use href="monos.svg#glc"/>) and my nodes ar e now non existant. Any tips?

Comment: You need to stay in d3. syntax so something like this should work `append("use").attr("href", "monos.svg#alt" )` You can also add x/y attributes as well as width and height attributes

Comment: Heard. Still no nodes are present in the output.

Comment: Those SVGs are nothing but circles and should be easy to reproduce with and standard data join with the fill functionally dependent on the data. Do you have more complicated SVGs in your full-blown problem?

Comment: Yes, over 100 different types of nodes in the full monos.SVG and they could be in any possible order.